# Scala inner case class not serializable

Tags: scala, serialization

I am trying to do a very basic serialization of a very simple case class in Scala:

```
import org.scalatest.wordspec.AnyWordSpecLike
import java.io.{ByteArrayOutputStream, ObjectOutputStream}

class PersistenceSpec extends AnyWordSpecLike{
  case class TestClass(name: String) extends Serializable

  def serializeSomething(): ByteArrayOutputStream = {
    val testItem = TestClass("My Thing")
    val bos: ByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos)
    oos.writeObject(testItem)
    bos
  }

  "serializeSomething" when {
    "executed" must {
      "successfully serialize" in {
        val outputStream = serializeSomething()
        println(outputStream.toString())
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this test I get a `java.io.NotSerializableException` on the call to `oos.writeObject(testItem)`, which makes no sense, since case classes automatically implement `Serializable`, and this is the simplest possible example.

However, if I paste the code for `TestClass` and `serializeSomething()` into `repl`, I am able to call the function, and it works just fine.

What is different when calling my function via `scalatest`, vs `repl` that would cause this exception?

One final note: If I change the call from `oos.writeObject(testItem)` to `oos.writeObject("Hello")`, it works fine, even when run from scalatest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to define `TestClass` outside of `PersistenceSpec`.
Inner class instances automatically get a reference to the instance of the outer class. So, when you write it out, it tries to serialize the `PersistenceSpec` instance as well, and that of course fails.

Comment: Probably alternatively OP can declare `class PersistenceSpec extends AnyWordSpecLike with Serializable`

Comment: I highly doubt all instance members in the entire hierarchy would be serializable though ...